# jQuery - Cannot load if not on a web server

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to load a page from my desktop, let's name it as `loadme.htm`.

Now I have an `index.htm` file, which will load the `loadme.htm`.

Why is it that it cannot load when I open the `index.htm` from my desktop? Some jQuery functions work here like `.trim()`, `.show()`, etc.. But if I put it on WAMP, it will load successfully.

Edit:
this is how I load the "loadme.htm"
`$.("#content").load("loadme.htm");`

Comment: How are you loading this file?"file > open?", "drag+drop"?

Comment: like this, $("#content").load("loadme.htm");

Comment: A good chance its a security issue. Browsers usually dont let javascript access any file off your desktop without explicit permissions.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `.load` makes an AJAX call to request the page.  That's why it is needing a web server.

Comment: Not really; usually browsers consider local files as «trusted» and give them extra permissions, such as sending http requests to any domain

Comment: .load() uses HTTP, therefore it requires a web server.

Comment: Anyways, one reason might be that jquery is missing a content-type header to use to determine *how* exactly to use that piece of content, when loading locally, while the server sends it correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have used jquery ajax load function to load your file. It will not work unless you are using http call for this. When you are opening from desktop it is using file protocol and failing. Other jquery functions like trim(), show() works because it does not have any dependency on protocol type and browser itself can handle those calls.